# WooCommerce isn't pulling attribute anymore

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Since updating Wordpress ( 4.9.4 ) / WooCommerce (3.3.1), for whatever reason the code below doesn't render the attribute value for 'Crane' associate to the item

Ex: on the search page
http://www.colorselectcoil.com/color-match-tool/
it renders out items with attributes

Finish: Smooth

Color Code: 280

Item Number: T24-280

**(here is where the manufactures should be but doesn't show now)**

The code I have  where the manufactures should show up is, for one of them, below

```
 <?php if( intval($_GET['filtering']) == 1 && intval($_GET['filter_manufacturer']) == 3885 &&  $collection = $product->get_attribute('Crane') ){
                echo '<div class="attribute-titles">Crane name:<br>';
                echo ($collection = $product->get_attribute('Crane') ) ? $collection : __('', 'woocommerce'); 
                echo '</div>';
             } ?>
```

Thoughts/feedback would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This code works… so your problem is may be that you can get the WC_Product object or that there is a problem with `$_GET`. What version of woocommerce? You should also give details on the context for this code, as this question is just unclear for now. So please edit your question.

Comment: I turned on debug and it says -  Notice: Undefined index: filtering in /woocommerce/content-product.php on line 61 which is where the above code start

Comment: So your problem is the `$_GET['filtering']` that should need to be in the URL like `?filtering=1&filter_manufacturer=3885` … so to avoid this you should use before `if(isset($_GET['filtering']) && isset($_GET['filter_manufacturer'])){ // your code }` … So the problem comes from the code that is generating the GET request (the filter)

Comment: So if I am following, something like this

Comment: <?php if(isset($_GET['?filtering=1&filter_manufacturer=3885']) && isset($_GET['filter_manufacturer'])){  
    echo '<div class="attribute-titles">Crane name:<br>';
    echo ($collection = $product->get_attribute('Crane') ) ? $collection : __('', 'woocommerce'); 
    echo '</div>';
    } ?>